# Controller has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I'm trying to refactor some controllers in Symfony 5 server, but suddenly I'm unable to change or create controllers because of the following error:

*'App\Controller{{ControllerName}}' has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?*

This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Shiftsummary;
use App\Entity\Station;
use App\Entity\Shift;
use App\Entity\Line;
use \Datetime;

class StartStationController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/start", name="StartStation")
     */

    public function route(Request $request)
    {
      ...
    }  }
```

This is the content of *service.yaml*

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true  
        autoconfigure: true 

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

The controllers are inside the *src/controller/* folder

[image]

Comment: Your controller is into a Controller folder ?

Comment: That's not enough to tell you what's wrong. If that's all there is in your controller, and your `services.yaml` has the appropriate defaults for Symfony 5, you should be fine. So something else must be wrong.

Comment: @GaryHoubre Yes, here's the content of service.yaml. I've tested this for empty bare bones controllers and I get the same error, so I'm assuming the content isn't what's causing the error

Comment: php version? Try to use 7.4.4 if possible.  Some of the earlier 7.4.x versions had preloading issues which caused mysterious errors such as these.  Might also try deleting var/cache completely.

Comment: @Cerad Php version is 7.4.4. Deleting var/cache folder solved the problem. Could you please post your answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue had to do with the cached files, deleting /var/cache made the error not occur.

Thanks go to Cerad for point this out.

Answer (score 12):

I have to add that if you set the wrong namespace, you get this error too:

```php
// src/Controller/Api/ProductController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class ProductController extends AbstractController {}
```

namespace must follow folders structure.

```php
namespace App\Controller\Api;
```

Comment: Yes, I also saw the error from only having the `namespace Controller;`

Answer (score 8):

this is just it, your controller did not have container injected. However, framework expects it to be done if your controller inherits from AbstractController.

in ControllerResolver.php:
[image]

**TLDR; What you need is to inject it.**

In your services.yaml, add the following setter call

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The strange thing is I inject it (in xml configuration), but it still hits this line... I also empty the cache with everything new that I try

Comment: In my case, I had to change the service id to the FQN. I do not know if the parameterized classname will be useful now. This is a bit of an old school project.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me! So weird that you have to somehow figure out these quirks.

Comment: The configuration key "calls" is unsupported for the service

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the class had just a different name than the file.

Answer (score 3):

None of above helped in my case.
I solved my case by:

```
calls:
    - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container/calls.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
namespace App\Controller;
```

with:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an error in the controller name when I used the bin/console command :

`bin/console make:controller APIController` this command add automatically suffix `-Controller` to the file.

Then the controller created is called `APIControllerController`.

Next I made a copy/paste of Auth0 guide to create API nammed `APIController`.

In the end the file had the name `APIControllerController.php` and the class `APIController`: you just had to change the filename and remove the duplicate -Controller suffix.

Or *- in general -* verify the name of file controller and the class name ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Another possibility, even more basic than the other suggestions:)

I had a simple controller that was `requiring` another PHP file, but in the course of some changes that required file couldn't even be compiled.  Fixing that required file resolved the somewhat misleading "has no container set..." message.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the controller as `autowire: true` will also invisibly add the `setContainer`. It solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
three steps
```

[1. edit ./config/services.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ziK8.png)

[2. edit ./config/routes.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rPNd.png)

[3. edit composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNOBT.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34962978)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the controller that gave me `has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber` was in another project that we included via `composer require`.

As autowiring/autoloading is controlled by the main application (not required applications, that are treated as libraries), and we are inheriting from an old project progressively being autowired, but not yet all perfect, I had to add the controller as a service in my main `services.yaml` with zero configuration:

For example, suppose the controller is `MySuperController` inside a composer-required project named `XaviMontero\DirtyBundle`, then in the main project I had to add this:

```
XaviMontero\DirtyBundle\Controller\MySuperController: ~
```

Merely adding this line makes the controller "appear as an injectable service" in the main app and all the problems disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I have just resolved this issue.
Turned out for me - I had miss typed __construct() as a private function, should be public